# How to refer to a figure from another source

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am writing an IEEE-style paper, in this paper, I want to refer to my readers a figure from another paper, that paper is also cited by my paper so it is in my bibliography list.

According to the IEEE style guide, I should use the style like "the reader is referred to [2, Fig.4]" instead of "Fig. 4 of [2]". The latter style is easy to write, just `Fig.4 in \cite{mycitation}` is OK, however, I don't know How to implement the former style.

Comment: The packages `xr` and `xcite` can help you, perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

Use the optional argument: \cite[Fig.~4]{fooBook}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{fooBook}
  Yuko Watanabe, 
  \textit{My experience with placeholder books in \LaTeX examples},
  Dummy publishing Company, Saitama, 
  zeroth edition,
  1984.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The command `\cite[Fig.~4]{lamport94}` does work with BibTeX, too. It also should work with other classes.